# Follow up, camber extendable table with the rack and pinion

Tags: furniture, tabletop, table-making

In [my last question](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3040/what-is-a-camber-exactly) of camber I was in the dark.
Through WW.SE I got good answers, now I know what it is, and why it's needed in extendable tables.

Now my question: is it necessary to put camber on the slide of an extendable table to compensate for eventual sagging when the table is extended to its utmost?

Comment: Are you referring to camber on the slide, or camber on the table top itself?

Comment: Could you please explain to me both? Thanks

Comment: Someone added the tag warp. I thinking that's a mistake. Because my question wasn't on wood that's warping. It was asked about camber that helps to correct a problem of sagging, when the table is extended.

Comment: @Nachmen That was me. I wanted to add some more tag context. I know it wasnt the best one.... closest to what I could think of.

Comment: Warping is the wood itself, here the table sags in when the table is extended. Or sometimes the edges go down. This how I understand camber to rectify these situation's. This is as far how I understand it logically and literally. Now  I need some help physically  to see how this works. I'm a do it yourself'ver. I didn't have vocational training in wood working. That why am asking help from the WW family.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to ask. A table may have some unavoidable camber, but I'm having trouble thinking of any reason to deliberately design that into the table. Most extentdng tables try to be reasonably flat in all configurations; they just don't always succeed.

Comment: First this is a learning expedition. I didn't know what camber means. Second now that I know through the help of WW, I would like to know how to utilize this in an extendable tables that it shouldn't sag. If there is a solution why not use it?

Comment: @Nachmen If you want this question answered, as requested numerous times, please provide *actual context*. Quotes that you read, links to material you are referencing, images of what you are talking about. As it stands your question makes about as much sense as "What are curves and how do I use them?" (I.e. not much sense, way too vague).

Comment: Wanting to build an extendable table it should extend without extra support (leg) from 118 to 177 with 3 leaves each one around 20". Here comes the camber in the tabletop shouldn't sag without support. Iwant to know, how it works, the diagram to make it, to understand when the table isn't extended why doesn't have the opposite effect.

Comment: Please provide **quotes** that you have read, **links** that you've looked at, **diagrams** that you have seen, and any other ***context*** that gives us a clue where you saw the word "camber" in the first place.

Comment: I came to it through Osborne Wood Products, as I was trying to gather information about extendable table the kind of mechanism's (slides, tracks etc.)  I fell upon this word camber I tried goggling the word I came up camber to align a wheel of a car it should ride better. The word was ruminating in my head, until I stumbled to this forum. I go to know what it means. But how it work is still a mystery for me. Also when you don't  use the  extension why doesn't it make  the opposite effect

Comment: I suspect that what you saw was a statement that, in a design such as the one you seem to be describing,  some camber is nearly inevitable.  But without seeing the actual quote,  in context,  we really can't explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table slides are those pieces of wood that join the two halves of a table and support the leaves.  The bigger the opening the more pieces necessary for each slide (Normally two slides per table, each made of two to several pieces of wood that mate in dovetail slots and rails.)  The slide set shown here employs rack and pinion mechanisms to assure that the slides move equal distances when the table is pulled apart.

[image]
[source](http://www.boisouvreswaterville.com/table-slides)

Any table with leaves is going to sag.

The problem to be solved is how to minimize the sag or how to make the table top level while the slides are sagging.  One way to achieve this would be slip well placed shims between the bottom of leaves and the sliders such that the entire table top becomes level.  Obviously, this is impractical.

Enter camber.

In this solution the slots in the sliders are slightly angled so that as the two halves of the table are pulled apart the center rises, negating the sag and creating a sort of stepped camber. I think that I have heard of the slots and rails being slight curved, also, but that sound exceedingly tricky.

The need for camber depends on your tolerance for sagging.  If I were making such a table, cambered slides would be near the top of my list for desired features.

If you are going to make a table with leaves you are likely to be well-advised to look at the commercially available slides (Google "wood table slides".) They are available with and without camber.

The above discussion applies to four legged tables. It is interesting to note that camber is also applied to pedestal tables where the natural sag occurs at the ends and camber is introduced in the slides so that as the table halves are separated the center goes down.

Comment: In this platform we're not allowed to thank so I'm not. Can you please show me by diagram or image how it looks in real. Thanks.

Comment: How do I  calculate how much I  need to camber the slides  is there a formula or I need to build the table and see how much the extended table sags?

Comment: I have not been able to find anything on internet about it.  There is certainly much trial and error which would be based on how tightly the slides fit one another. the number of pieces per slide and probably least importantly the wood used.  Partly in response to your question that was put on hold, I would suggest that you buy pre-constructed slides.

Comment: The problem is I  live in Antwerp Belgium, I looked all over the internet. You could buy it in the U.S. In Belgium I don't find nothing.

Comment: This link (http://www.siso.dk/pdf/Table%20Slides%20&%20Accessories.pdf) to a Danish manufacturer has mainly metal table slides, but on page 12 displays wooden slides.

Comment: you did your  duty to me and to the whole forum. This is what it's all about share information for the benefit of others.